# How to call/handle different event handlers for same event on same element? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm curious here, I know that it's possible to attach multiple event handlers to same element if I use `DOM Level 2` method called `addEventListener`(), so I'm wondering if we have this situation:

```
someButton.addEventListener("mouseover", showHint, false);

someButton.addEventListener("mouseover", showHintTwo, false);
```

Is this possible in real world scenario? Example above ^

And how could I choose when I want to call `showHint` and when I want to call `showHintTwo`,is it possible to handle it/separate it somehow ... because both of the event handlers will fire when `mouseover` happened?

Thanks guys

Cheers

Comment: @CyrusCuenca Can multiple event listeners/handlers be added to the same element using javascript? That is not my question! I know it is possible  but I'm wondering how to handle them separatedly, how to call different handler on same event whenever I want... ....

Comment: I guess if there were a flag of some sorts on the button you could have a fork from where you could have two functionalities.. but then again you would not need to have two handlers.. Instead a simple if else would allow you to figure out what to do when...

Answer (score 1):

Like this? https://codepen.io/cyruscuenca/pen/xmrxob

It doesn't make much sense, but it satisfies what you want.

- 2 event handlers.
- You can choose to which block is actually shown with the toggle.

I would personally add one event handler and pass in a condition like:

```
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function(condition) {
    switch(condition) {
      case x:
      // code block
      break;
    case y:
      // code block
      break;
    default:
      // code block
  } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A good way to handle this would be to create a separate hint counter variable and then show the relevant hint of your choice. How you want to update the counter will determine when which hint will be shown.

```
let hintCounter = 1;

function showHint() {
    switch(hintCounter) {
        case 1: // show first hint
        case 2: // show second hint
    }

    hintCounter++;
}

someButton.addEventListener("mouseover", showHint, false);
```

If you need to set the second hint to show after a set amount of time, take a look at the `setTimeout()` function in JS.